# USB peripherals don't work on login screen

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, login-screen

I just noticed something odd, when I'm on the login screen of my Windows 10 pc, my keyboard and mouse don't receive a signal - they're not powered.

When I first boot the computer, I have to enter my bitlocker password, my keyboard still works during this. Then once I get to the login screen, I'm asked to press ctrl+alt+del to login (It's a company computer, signing in to AD) but I can't.

It seems only the front USB ports work on this screen, this never happened before today. Once I'm logged in, my keyboard and mouse will only work on the USB 3.0 ports on the back, the 2.0 ports still won't work.

Any help in resolving this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Go to BIOS and enable legacy support for mouse and keyboard and try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried that and legacy support was already enabled.

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this?  I have a similar problem.

Comment: @MikeFulton the problem just kinda went away for me.. Sorry